# Printing numbers without exponential notation in Maxima

Tags: maxima, simplification

I have trouble with WordMat, when calculating with Maxima, which didn't occur before, but started recently. When i calculate something that either results in x00000 or 0,0000x i get the result returned as its scientific expression, IE `x*10^5` or `x*10^-5`. Even though this is correct, i would rather have it returned as a full number.

This only tends to happen when the number of 0's goes beyonda certain number, in the case of decimal numbers its from xe-5 and higher numbers its from xe9 and beyond. I can not turn this off in the settings as far as i can see, but it seems to be a setting in maxima simplification, with the variable option "expon" from what i found here:

file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/WordMat/Maxima-5.45.1/share/maxima/5.45.1/doc/html/maxima_46.html

Does anyone know of a way to either change the setting in wordmat, or edit the simplification rules in maxima?

I tried:

- Turning on and off most setting in wordmat
- Restarting my pc
- Reinstalling WordMat
- Looking through the manual for maxima/wordmat and looking for changeable settings

Comment: Unfortunately, in Maxima, the smallest and largest floating point numbers which are printed without exponential notation are fixed and cannot be changed. In the current version (Maxima 5.46), the smallest is 0.001 and the largest is 10000000.0. These limits are hardcoded in the program to format numbers for output, and I don't see a way to change them. I will raise the issue on the Maxima mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to control the printed format of numbers, I think the best general answer is to use `printf` to specify exactly how to print the numbers.  For what you want, `printf(true, "~f", x)` will print the value of `x` without ever introducing exponential format.

(The default maxima output is basically "~g" which basically automatically chooses between "~f" and "~e" depending on the value of `x`).

Perhaps a future version of maxima will allow you to change the default output range, but in general `printf` is the method to use if you want fine-grained control of the output.